# How to get emoji character from the emoji string

Tags: android, string, android-edittext, char, emoji

I want to get emoji character from the String which one I get from the `EditText` but when I will try to get the character that time converted into `unsupported character`. so can any one help me for this issue because will try so many time but not be getting the expected output.
***Emoji Character String***

**Unsupported character**
�

**Code:**

```
String charStr = edChar.getText().toString();
Character strChar = charStr.charAt(0);
Log.d("TAG_Char", strChar.toString());
```